# How to generate a random number in Ruby from a specific minimum range to a maximum variable?

Tags: ruby

How to create a random number generator in Ruby? I know there are ways to do it like `rand(0..9)` to generate a random number from 0 to 9, or `rand(0…9)` to generate a random number from 0 to 8. But what if I say `rand(0.. *variable*)` to generate a random number from 0 to the value of that variable?

Look at the code below for a clearer example:

*Suppose I’m creating a number guessing game*

```
print “Enter a number: “
max_num = gets
max_num.to_i #converting it into an integer to print it out with strings

random_num = rand(0.. **max_num**)
```

Comment: For future reference, have a look at how I formatted your code.

Comment: Oh hey, it is my first time asking a question on stack overflow so I kinda messed it up but thanks

Answer (score 2):

`max_num.to_i` does not change the string to an integer. The string is still a string. The method `to_i` returns an integer that's not the string.

```
irb> s = "123"
irb> p s.to_i
123
irb> p s
"123"
```

What you need to do is to assign the return value to a variable (even the same variable will do) and use that variable, like

```
max_num = max_num.to_i
random_num = rand(0..max_num)
```

Actually, in Ruby, though there are lots of methods that can change the internal state of the receiver (like `Array#map!` and `String#strip!`), there's no method that can change the type of the receiver.

Comment: Or along with the first assignment: `max_num = gets.to_i` – based on the variable's name, it should never refer to a string.

Comment: Omgggg thank you so much, it did help me!!!